# How to implement the Search View Docked mode

Tags: android, material-components-android, android-search, material3

Currently, I am using the Material 3 library to code my application's design.
In the official Material 3 website (m3.material.io), in the Search section, at the bottom there is a picture of a Search View that is in docked mode. We could also see the same happening in the Google Messages app which uses the same behaviour. Though I was not able to find any clue whatsoever on how to code this Search View style.

Here is also a link to the official Material 3 website.
https://m3.material.io/components/search/specs

Edit: After going through the alpha version of the library I was able to find a jetpack compose library that support this behaviour (it is also called as a DockedSearchBar) but since I'm using MDC-Android this solution can't unfortunately help me.

Comment: Are you using Compose?

Comment: Sorry should've mentioned in the post but I'm using MDC-Android.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://m3.material.io/components/search/overview) states that the Search component is not yet natively implemented in Jetpack Compose, but is available in Flutter and MDC-Android.

For details on the MDC-Android implementation you can read the relevant documentation [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Search.md). If you'd like to use it in Compose you can [use the AndroidView composable](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/migrate/interoperability-apis/views-in-compose).

The docked mode search view in the documentation you linked is an example of how it should be used - To implement the docked mode search view, you would have to create your own container with the desired size and behaviour, and have the search view take up the entire size of that container.

Comment: I'm using MDC-Android but I wasn't able to find any code that would make that possible. The normal full-screen SearchView is very straight forward to code but I couldn't find anything about the docked mode in the github page either.

Comment: That's because for docked mode you need to make your own container and put the SearchView within it. How you implement the container will depend on your app.

Comment: Could I ask you to be a little more specific? For example what kind of container does it have to be or if you could give out an exmaple that would be awesome thank you. I tried multiple things but the Search View ends up using the full-screen style and fits itself inside the container.

Comment: That's the intended behaviour - You need to make a container using a View or a Layout that is the size and shape you want, and the SearchView will fill it.

Comment: That still doesn't work because of 2 reasons. 1. There's no way to make the SearchView rounded (I tried using background but it still showed its old design) 2. The sizings are messed up and the docummentation doesn't mention anything about how to change the sizes.